# Questions about adding image to thumbnailphoto attribute from Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

I've been using adldap to add user image to the thumbnailphoto attribute for updating user profile information through active diectory.

Here is what i did  as follows:

I use code:

**$modified = $adldap->user()->modify($account,  $attributes );**

to update the user account with specific attributes (ex. thumbnailphoto)

however, when I add information to $attribute.
I convert the image url to base64 string ( ex. **"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAMCAg.......")**
and then decode those string and update to $attributes. even though the thumbnailphoto attribute has value, but it can't display real image (i checked with software name "AD photo edit free edition")

the decoded value i got  as follows: 
**"\u00c3\u0083\u00c2\u00bf\u00c3\u0083\u00c2\u0098\u00c3\u0083\u0......"**

Which I compared with other user active directory thumbnailphoto attribute,  their image display perfectly .

their thumbnailphoto attribute value is as follows:

**"\u00ff\u00d8\u00ff\u00e0\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001......"**

I think those are hexdecimal value , and i try to convert my original encode value(**"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAMCAg.......")**)  into hex and update to the thumbnailphoto attribute  and turn out to be

"\ffd8ffe0..... "
but still not similar to the one that I got from the other users

Just wondering , what is the correct way to update image to active directory

Thanks

Comment: Just one thing to add - `\u00ff` is a unicode hex value. I'm not sure if it can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows PowerShell for this one,

My code:

```
# Set the network path of the user pictures.
$NetworkPath = "Path were the photos are stored"
# Get all the filesnames without the extension, every picture inside this folder should be named after the username of the user.
$UsersNames = Get-ChildItem -Path "$NetworkPath"| % {$_.BaseName}
# For each file name (username) go and convert into digital (byte encoding) the file then store it in a temporary value ($Photo).
# Then update the users jpegPhoto attribute on Active Directory with the $photo
foreach ($User in $UsersNames){
$Photo = [Byte[]](Get-Content "$NetworkPath\$User.jpg" -Encoding Byte)
Set-ADUser $User -Replace @{jpegPhoto=$Photo}
}

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Setup\Test\*.jpg' | Set-ImageSize -Destination 'C:\Setup\Test\new\' -WidthPx 96 -HeightPx 96 -Verbose
```

I had to download the Set-ImageSize so I can resize the images.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Resize-Image-File-f6dd4a56

The script explains itself I hope this is informative for you.